# Running submit() twice to submit to different forms at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I have the following two forms

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="submit" id="save" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

The two forms are in very oposite and irrelevant places on a page. I want to be able to submit them both at the same time when save is hit. I also know that save is only for second form but it is this way, because I was instructed to add the upper form later after the form with field2 was created. I will correct it.

My js is the following

```
$('#save').on('click', function(event){
    form1 = $("#form1");
    form2 = $(#"form2");
    event.preventDefault() //Some other checks happen before submission that's why I am preventing it
    //Checks

    form2.submit();
    form1.submit();
});
```

But in my backend only field1 is on the request.POST(django) dictionary. I believe because I submitted it second. When I only had to submit only one (form2) everything worked. But I can't do both. How can I submit two different forms at the same time?

Comment: You can't do that because on `form2.submit();` the control will be transferred and you lose the second. The best option will be to get the field values first and then post it together.

Comment: How can I post them together?Without using form1 or form2 submit function?Without ajax

Comment: Today you will learn about a thing called Ajax since that is the only solution other than submitting them to hidden iframes. Other than that, it ain't possible to do two things

Comment: Lol...I know about ajax..:)...Just don't want to use it in this case.DOn't mind doing it if I don't have another way..

Comment: @Apostolos: Well, ajax makes this easy, specially with jQuery `form.serialize()`. Serialize both forms and send the data to the server in a single post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular instance, you can send it together like:

```
$('#save').on('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var form = $('<form method="post"></form>'); 
     $(form).append($('#field1'));
     $(form).append($('#field2'));

     $(form).appendTo('body');

     $(form).submit();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If both forms have the same action, can't you wrap all fields within one `<form>` tag?

This way, you submit fields from both forms at the same time, without the need of JS as proposed in another answer.

Comment: Yes you are right but in the question the user said that the input fields are far apart (in different) places in the html document. Might not be possible to wrap them in one form tag.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, that the two forms are very far appart.I prefered the answer given by